# Fail generate UUID datatype (uniqueidentifier) from sql server using laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, nginx, sqlsrv

i have problem with my php config..
in my local computer, all uuid run normally.. but when i run in my server, the uuid fail generate, like

> b"uT‹ñÑ?zA´ñ‘˜$°\x02’

in my local i'm using apache, and in my server i'm using nginx..
all same php version and sqlserver version in my local and my server

what the wrong in my config php.ini on that server ?

please help me ..

Comment: Can you check where **exactly** the problem occurs? In your application, in the database server on writing?

Answer (score 1):

probabbly stringify in uuid field from sqlserver driver for php (dblib)
you can add options in PDO call like

```
        PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER => true,
```

Answer (score -2):

there no problem in your php.ini , okay 
the problem is when you generate your uuid , Laravel don't understand it when you put it in linux okay.
you juste need to check , your model (make sure that you set the type column as String ) , and check the query ,
this is an example :

```
    $user_list = DB::table('users')
                ->select(DB::raw('CAST(user.id AS NVARCHAR(36)) AS id'))
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->first();
```

Using the cast , will help you to get your uuid correctly.

Comment: Can you explain that further? How did you guess that Linux is involved here?